# Assume now $f \circ g : A \rightarrow A$ is a bijection. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are both bijections.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a finite set, $f: A \rightarrow A$ and $g: A \rightarrow A$. Assume now $f \circ g : A \rightarrow A$ is a bijection. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are both bijections.

I know from that since $f \circ g$ is surjective (since its bijective) then $f$ is surjective. Then by the pigeonhole principle, $f$ is also injective, thus making $f$ bijective.

However, how do you prove that $g$ is also bijective?

Comment: Suppose toward a contradiction...

Comment: The injectivity of $g$ follows as quickly as the surjectivity of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Suppose $g$ was not injective, then $\exists a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $a_1 \neq a_2$ but $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$. In which case $f(g(a_1))=f(g(a_2))$. This contradicts the injectivity of $f \circ g$.

Now try surjectivity.